# Comparing a word from any of the elements in 2 arrays

Tags: c

I'm new to c and I'm trying to figure out why my program isn't working.

It's supposed to scan 2 lists of arrays and find if a string from any element of an array matches the a string from any element of another array.

```
int i, j;
int max;
char word1[10][10];
char word2[10][10];

scanf("%d", &max);

for(i = 0; i < max; i++)
    scanf("%s", word1[i]);

for(j = 0; j < max; j++)
    scanf("%s", word2[j]);

for(i = 0; i < max; i++)
{
    for(j = 0; j < max; j++)
    {
        if (word1[i] == word2[j])
        {
            printf("yay");

        }

    }
}
```

For some reason, the if condition never makes it through, and I'm stuck, any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if (word1[i] == word2[j])
```

`word1[i]` and `word2[j]` are both strings , so don't compare like this. Use `strcmp` instead -

```
if (strcmp(word1[i],word2[j])==0)
```

Comment: But why can't you compare 2 of the same string with ==?

Comment: @Rig Array names generally points to first element of string , and you end up comparing the base address of array , not content , and therefore ,it will be false .

Comment: Essentially, @Rig, because C does not have a string type worthy of the name.